# Trouble with Rust lifetimes: impl uses anonymous lifetime and function uses <'a>, changing the lifetimes to match leads to an error

Tags: rust, lifetime

You can run the code snippet [here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=665fcb4c46dde25b2a7a8912ef448cf0). I removed a bunch of irrelevant functions and fields of the struct to make things simpler to analyze.

```
#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct Turtle<'a>{
    children: Vec<&'a Turtle<'a>>,
}

impl Turtle<'_>{
    pub fn new() -> Turtle<'static> {
        Turtle {children: Vec::new()}
    }
    pub fn add_child<'a>(&self, t: &'a Turtle<'a>) {
        &self.children.push(t);
    }
}
```

The error is

```
   |
11 |         &self.children.push(t);
   |                             ^ lifetime mismatch
   |
   = note: expected reference `&Turtle<'_>`
              found reference `&Turtle<'a>`
note: the lifetime `'a` as defined on the method body at 10:22...
  --> src/lib.rs:10:22
   |
10 |     pub fn add_child<'a>(&self, t: &'a Turtle<'a>) {
   |                      ^^
note: ...does not necessarily outlive the lifetime `'_` as defined on the impl at 6:13
  --> src/lib.rs:6:13
   |
6  | impl Turtle<'_>{
   |             ^^
```

The problem appears to be that since impl has an anonymous lifetime, &self has type Turtle<'_>, so self.children has anonymous lifetime, meaning push expects a Turtle<'_>. I came up with 2 ideas to fix this, namely either changing impl to <'a> or the lifetime of parameter t to <'_>, but neither worked. I understand how to make sure the lifetime of a single function is correct, but when it comes to various functions, structs, and impls all connected together, things start to become unclear.

Comment: You could have two `impl`s: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=8b9d52b82ecfc75fd89b6585835e0928

Comment: @ForceBru I would prefer to have one impl that contains all the functions such as add_child and whatever else I left out. Your idea works for now, but when I start adding back functions to impl<'a> Turtle<'a>, I get all sorts of new errors.

Comment: compile ok solution: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=f09890a74d2753647a642b90f39284ee

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your struct requires a lifetime, which you have chosen to call ‘a’. That lifetime is then ‘given to’ or ‘shared with‘ self.children. Later, you implement your struct for the anonymous lifetime, which is the lifetime that the struct definition states self.children must also share. However, your ‘new‘ function implies creation of self.children with a ‘static‘ lifetime (and ‘static != ‘_ as ‘_ could be shorter than ‘static). Further your add child method requires a (plausibly) entirely separate lifetime which you also call ‘a’ (just because you called it ‘a’ does not make it the same as the ‘a’ you named in the struct definition). Try creating a new struct that takes a type rather than a lifetime (say T or V, for example)? If neither have bounds then they will be essentially equal. The same applies to lifetimes.

The actual solution lies in matching your lifetimes. Because of the self-referential nature of your struct you cannot use the anonymous lifetime, as the compiler needs to know that the lifetimes match when adding children. What is below now compiles. Note the use of Self to infer the lifetime <'a> upon creation. You could also have used Turtle<'a> but I personally would consider using Self easier, as it avoids the additional lifetime reference. Also, in order for your add_child method to work, the reference to "self" needs to be mutable (see &mut self). This is because you are modifying the contents of self.children and therefore mutating the struct.

Note that this will work for "any" lifetime, whether you have called it 'a or 'z or anything else. The point is that the compiler can infer that the lifetimes of everything involved are matching.

```
    #[derive(Debug)]
    pub struct Turtle<'a> {
        children: Vec<&'a Turtle<'a>>,
    }

    impl<'a> Turtle<'a> {
        pub fn new() -> Self {
            Self { children: Vec::new() }
        }

        pub fn add_child(&mut self, t: &'a Turtle<'a>) {
            self.children.push(t);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is this what you mean? https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=56daaca30fedbf1d770b779a69ceabba It doesn't work, and the compiler asks me to add back 'static to new().

Comment: Sorry, it was admittedly slightly more complicated. Updated.